# Include custom index chapter title in table of contents in ConTeXt

Tags: table-of-contents, context, chapters, indexing

## Problem

The following code is used to prevent pagination from being applied to the index:

```
\setuphead[chapter,section][
  number=no,
  page=yes,
  continue=no,
]

\definehead[StyleIndex][chapter]
\setuphead[StyleIndex][
  page=no,
]
```

The index is typeset as follows:

```
\startbackmatter
  \chapter{Index}
  \placeindex
\stopbackmatter
```

That code causes the chapter title to be displayed on a new page, which I can avoid (as desired) using:

```
\startbackmatter
  \StyleIndex{Index}
  \placeindex
\stopbackmatter
```

However, that causes the Index to be removed from the table of contents (ToC), which is not desired. I had expected that it would inherit the *chapter*'s behaviour and be included in the ToC.

## Question

How would you create a distinct style for chapter headings that differs from the heading style used for an index page while having both included in the ToC?

Comment: Use `\setuplist[content][list={chapter, section, StyleIndex}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New defined structure elements are not added to the table of contents by
default. You have to add the particular entry to the list. This can be done
globally with the `list` key of `\setuplist`:

```
\setuplist
  [content]
  [list={chapter, section, newSection}]
```

Or it can directly be specified as an argument to
`\placecombinedlist`:

```
\starttitle [title=Contents]
  \placecombinedlist
    [content]
    [list={chapter, section, newSection}]
\stoptitle
```

And note that unnumbered structure elements like `title`,
`subject` are not added to the table of contents when
`incrementnumber` is not set to `list`, which is not the default.
Here's a complete example:

```
\definehead
  [newSection]
  [section]

\definehead
  [newTitle]
  [title]
  [incrementnumber=list]

\setuplist
  [content]
  [list={chapter, section, newSection, newTitle}]

\starttext

\completecontent

\startsection [title=Foo]
\input knuth
\stopsection

\startnewSection [title=Bar]
\input knuth
\stopnewSection

\startnewTitle [title=newTitle]
\input knuth
\stopnewTitle

\stoptext
```