# ConTeXt: Use deeptextcommand and custom register

Tags: context, indexing, framed

## Background

Looking to emphasize the first letter of the index chapter title.

## Code

The following code does not work as expected:

```
\defineframed[StyleChapterFramed][
  frame=off,
]

\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
    \framed[align=right, frame=off]{%
      \startoverlay {
          \getfirstcharacter{#1}%
          \firstcharacter%
        }
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}

  \setuphead[chapter][
    deeptextcommand=\StyleChapter,
  ]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
  \completecontent
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
  \startchapter[
    title={Chapter},
    reference=sec:chapter,
  ]

  \startsection[
    title={Section},
    reference=sec:section,
  ]

  \startsubsection[
    title={Equipment},
    reference=sec:equipment,]
    \input knuth
  \stopsubsection

  \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
  \completeindex
  %\placeindex
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

This produces the following compile error:

```
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.1 -> \headtext {index}
! Use of \csname\endcsname doesn't match its definition.

system          > tex > error on line 51 in file ex.tex: Use of  ...
```

## Problem

The problem seems to be the following line:

```
  \completeindex
```

The document compiles when replaced with:

```
  \chapter{Index}
  \placeindex
```

## Update

The code also fails when using:

```
\setupregister[index][%
  alternative=A,%
]
```

Although it seems to be a different problem.

## Output

I have achieved the following for chapter titles (inset to bottom-right, followed by a page break):

[image: Chapter TItle]

Yet what I cannot seem to accomplish is override the chapter style to create a different index style title such as (at the top of a page, without a page break):

[image: Index Title]

This might be related to: [Include custom index chapter title in table of contents in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134357/include-custom-index-chapter-title-in-table-of-contents-in-context?noredirect=1#comment303528_134357)

## Question

How would you use a `deeptextcommand` *and* a custom [register](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupregister) in ConTeXt?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exactly you want to achive. You might not need the overlay or deeptextcommand to achive that. But it's hard to tell without knowing how it's supposed to look like.

Comment: The error is caused by your use of ``\getfirstcharacter``, which is a wrapper around ``getfirstcharacter()`` in [``syst-aux.lua``](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/syst-aux.lua#l26).
The label of the index heading is generated dynamically, so it expands to ``\headtext {index}``.
Calling ``getfirstcharacter()`` on that extracts the *backslash* which leads to an instant fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ConTeXt mailing list, a work-around was proposed:

```
\cldcontext{string.sub("#1",1,1)}%
```

This becomes:

```
\define[1]\StyleChapter{%
  \StyleChapterFramed{%
    \framed[align=right, frame=off]{%
      \startoverlay
        \color[blue]{%
          \StyleFontChapterCharacter%
          \cldcontext{string.sub("#1",1,1)}%
        }
        \vskip-1.9em\hskip1.2em#1
      \stopoverlay
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ``\cldcontext{string.sub("#1", 1, 1)}``.
Strings indices start from 1.

Comment: @phg: It appears both `0,1` and `1,1` work in this case.